# What does 'initial' mean in unity UI toolkit?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

im trying to adjust the text size on my unity ui with UI toolkit but can't seem to figure out what this 'initial' mean. I also failed to find any documentation about this. Could anyone enlighten me?
[Unity UI toolkit screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0sZI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Initial" is a parameter that also appears in CSS and other styling languages for font sizes and scaling. It means that the font size will be equal to the standard font size (usually defined in the font asset itself). The value itself will be the variation from this starting value.

You're right though, this feature [is not documented at all](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ui.builder@1.0/manual/uib-styling-ui-text.html). The % font size attribute is also poorly documented and supported, and all of the examples only use **pixels** for sizing.